# Getting subdirectories of a path that have specific file extensions

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

I was wondering if there was a way to only retrieve the directories that have certain extensions.

For example

```
List<string> directories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceTextBox.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

would give me all of the directories and subdirectories inside the path I gave it. However I only want it to retrieve the directories that have a .jpg or .png file inside of them.

```
List<string> directories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceTextBox.Text, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
directories.addRange(Directory.GetDirectories(sourceTextBox.Text, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList());
```

Any way I could do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No guarantees in terms of performance, but for each directory you could check its files to see if it contains any with the matching extension:

```
List<string> imageDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceTextBox.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(d => Directory.EnumerateFiles(d)
        .Select(Path.GetExtension)
        .Where(ext => ext == ".png" || ext == ".jpg")
        .Any())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way of doing it, You can try something like this

```
var directories = Directory
.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(x=> Directory.EnumerateFiles(x, "*.jpg").Any() || Directory.EnumerateFiles(x, "*.png").Any())
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the file matching criteria and then you can get their Path minus file name using `Path.GetDirectoryName` and add it to the `HashSet`. `HashSet` would only keep the unique entries.

```
HashSet<string> directories = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceTextBox.Text, 
                                             "*.png",  
                                             SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    directories.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
}
```

For checking multiple file extensions you have to enumerate all files and then check for extension for each file like:

```
HashSet<string> directories = new HashSet<string>();
string[] allowableExtension = new [] {"jpg", "png"};
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceTextBox.Text,
                                             "*", 
                                             SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
    if (allowableExtension.Contains(extension))
    {
        directories.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
    }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to also find the .jpg extension, would I do another foreach loop?

Comment: @KelseyAbreu, YES and No. You can `EnumerateFiles` without any wild card specified and then check for each file if the extension is `png` or `jpg` and then add it to the file.